# Enterprise iOS app cloud storage

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, cloud, storage

I'm trying hard to get my mind wrapped around how you would be able to store files in the cloud from an enterprise app without requesting the user to log in.

The background:
I'm developing an iOS app that will be distributed to certain employees in our company. As of today we already have an app that uses an FTP server to upload user created files. In this new app, I would like to skip the FTP server and instead use some sort of cloud storage (DropBox, Google Drive etc.)

The users will upload some files (around 1-2 uploads per day) to the cloud service, and people at our HQ will be able to look at these files.

I don't want to have each employee create a personal cloud drive account that would be linked with a "master" account. Rather, I want this specific application to always upload it's files to the cloud storage "master" account. Is this even possible?

Since only our employees have access to the app, I don't see the security factor as limiting. The information sent is not of use to anyone else than our company (no high-security stuff).

Is it possible to "hard-code" an OAuth token that corresponds with a certain account that the app always uses? Are there other possibilities that I'm not aware of (other than FTP or cloud storage)?

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards,
Jens Nilsson

Answer (score 0):

how about use one dropbox account and hard code it in your app? then your enterprise user can upload their files respectively. surely you need do some trick to make no any file with duplicate name.

Comment: Is it possible to hard code a DropBox account in the app then? I've got the impression that to create an OAuth token, someone will have to log in to a DropBox account. That is the part that I want to get away from. Correct me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: I think everything the dropbox need you already have including token, account name and password. I think you can make login become invisible to user.

Comment: I will look into this and accept your answer if this is a possibility. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

i am developing one iOs application that uses a parse cloud service to upload user generated files.

in that parse service, user dont need to create a account separately.each and every user can be able to uploads files to cloud where user can be able to visit all the files which is in the cloud which is created by some other user.

suppose if we want limit some user files accessibility or upload files privilege also we can achieve that through using the parse.

i just remember parse is not open source.